# Elasticsearch 5 - Field distinct values without aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with a time-based index storing syslog events.

All the data is coming from different sources (PCs).

Suppose I have this kind of events:

```
timestamp = 0
source = PC-1
event = event_type_1

timestamp = 1
source = PC-1
event = event_type_1

timestamp = 1
source = PC-2
event = event_type_1
```

I want to make a query that will retrieve all the distinct value of "source" field for documents where match event = event_type_1

I am expecting to have all exact values (no approximations). 
To achieve it I have written a cardinality query with an aggregation specifying  the correct size, because I have no prior knowledge of the number of distinct sources. I think this is a expensive work to do as it consumes a lot of memory.
Is there any other alternative to get this done?